# Including header file of HIDAPI library built by Conan

Tags: cmake, build, header, conan, hidapi

I built Hidapi with Conan. Cmake configure successfully, but Cmake build failed. Reason: include "hidapi.h" not found, "hid.c" not found, "libusb.h" not found. Which of headers I must include. In Cmakelists I used include_directories(${hidapi_include_dirs}), target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} hidapi::hidapi), find_package(hidapi REQUIRED) as a rule.

**Cmakelists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(scanner CXX)
message("Building project: " ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CONAN_DISABLE_CHECK_COMPILER "1")

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/menu.cpp
    src/utility.cpp
    src/commands.cpp
    src/commands_sequencies.cpp
)

set(HEADERS
    src/enums/function_name.h
    src/commands_sequencies.h
    src/commands.h
    src/menu.h
    src/utility.h
    src/CppConsoleTable.hpp
)

add_subdirectory(src/utfcpp)
add_subdirectory(src/hidapi)

if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    conan_basic_setup()
else()
    message(WARNING "The file conanbuildinfo.cmake doesn't exist, you have to run conan install first")
endif()

set(modules "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${modules})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${modules}")
file(COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Findspdlog.cmake DESTINATION ${modules})
file(COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Findfmt.cmake DESTINATION ${modules})
#file(COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Findhidapi.cmake DESTINATION ${modules})
#file(COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Findlibusb.cmake DESTINATION ${modules})
#file(COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Findlibudev.cmake DESTINATION ${modules})

include(FindPkgConfig)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)
#find_package(hidapi REQUIRED)
#find_package(libusb REQUIRED)
#find_package(libudev REQUIRED)

list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CONAN_BOOST_ROOT})
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
add_compile_definitions(_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS json log system REQUIRED)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)

# -------- Firmware downloal library ---------- #
find_library(FWLIB_TO_INCLUDE appdownload.a src/lib)
find_path(FWLIB_INCLUDES fwdlinterface.h src/include)
include_directories(${FWLIB_INCLUDES})
# -------- Firmware downloal library ---------- #

#include_directories(${hidapi_INCLUDES})
if(Boost_FOUND)
message("-- Boost found... Linking...")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#include_directories(${hidapi_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} utf8cpp hidapi::hidapi spdlog::spdlog)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::thread Boost::system Boost::json Boost::log)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${FWLIB_TO_INCLUDE})
endif()
```

**conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
boost/1.80.0
spdlog/[>=1.4.1]
hidapi/0.14.0

[options]
boost:header_only=False
boost:without_stacktrace=True

[generators]
cmake
virtualenv
cmake_find_package
```

In code above hidapi is build from sources, building with conan is commented.
If to uncomment build with conan(find_package), configuring is successful, but including "hidapi.h" or other headers above makes Cmake fall on build.
How to include library? I don't understand. Any with will be appreciated

Comment: This is using very legacy generators like ``cmake`` and ``cmake_find_package``, instead of the recommended ones ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain``. The recommended version anyway is Conan 2.0, while this seems a very ancient Conan 1.X versions, is this for any specific reason?

Comment: This would be missing many details to reproduce correctly, I suggest submitting an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues instead

Comment: @drodri our project works on Conan 1.xx.xx, we didn't pass to new version.

Comment: ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain`` have been available in Conan 1.X for years now, deprecating and superseding the ``cmake`` and ``cmake_find_package`` generators

Comment: @drodri using cmakedeps and cmaketoolchain invokes error "not found generator".  What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Update to a more modern Conan 1.X version?

Comment: I have 1.61.0, isn't it enough?

Comment: It definitely should be enough, it might be something else. I suggest reporting it to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues. I also see that ``add_subdirectory(src/hidapi)`` is not commented, but that is confusing if ``hidapi`` is expected to be a dependency and not built in the project